# rolling medians

Tags: r, smoothing

I need to do rolling medians..(running medians) in R of 3 and 7 and plot them. I know that using `smooth(x,"3R")` iterates until it converges. But I want to do running medians of 7 to compare, which I am entering as for my variable:

```
xR7 <- rollmedian(x,7)
Age # at Age
0   558
1   513
2   582
3   604
4   584
5   566
6   562
7   524
8   529
9   430
10  497
```

How do I know when it converges? Is there a test?

Answer (score 4):

Repeated smoothing with medians will progressively eat away at both ends of `x` until it vanishes.  You need some convention to assign values to the running medians at the ends.  One way is "copying on": just replicate the first valid value back to the beginning and the last valid value on to the end.

One way to check for convegence--a fairly severe one, but probably safe in this context--is to stop only when successive iterations are exactly the same.  Use `identical`.

This leads to the following procedure:

```
library(zoo)

rollmedianR <- function(x, k=3) {
  n <- length(x)
  k.low <- floor((k+1)/2)
  k.high <- n + 1 - k.low
  repeat {
    y <- rollmedian(x, k, na.pad=TRUE)
    y[1:k.low] <- y[k.low]; y[k.high:n] <- y[k.high]
    if (identical(x, y)) break
    x <- y
  }
  return(y)
}
```

As a test, let's compare it to `smooth` on some random data:

```
set.seed(17)
x <- sin(seq(0, 2*pi, 2*pi/1000)) + rnorm(1001, 0.25)
0 >= var((smooth(x,"3R") - rollmedianR(x, 3)), rep(0.0, length(x)))
```

> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yo7d1.png) TRUE

Because there's no variation in the differences of the two results, they agree.  Good.  (By the way, this variance test would work well inside `rollmedianR` to check for convergence in place of `identical`: it is more robust to floating point errors.  In principle this is not a concern for medians, because no numerical changes are occurring--values are just being copies around--but in other applications having such robustness is crucial.)

A plot can show what a long running median does:

```
plot(x, col="Gray", cex=0.8)
lines(rollmedianR(x,37), lwd=2, col="Red")
```

[image: Plot of data and a running median]